# Finite field extension over the rationals need only one generator?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Some book stated (without proof) that in every finite dimensional field over the rationals of dimension $n$, there is an element of degree $n$ (i.e. any field $Q[\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n]$ is of the form $Q[\theta]$).

Can someone give a confirmation, reference, proof-sketch, hint?

And is there a similar result for $Z$ ?

Comment: What do you mean "$Z$"? If you meant $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , the integers, this is *not* a field.

Comment: See the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem).

Comment: @Git Gud: Thanks! That answers my (first) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [primitive element theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem). A quick Google search will give you several different sets of self-contained notes that include the proof.

If your second question is asking whether given a collection of algebraic numbers $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n$, there exists a $\theta$ such that $\mathbf{Z}[\theta] = \mathbf{Z}[\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n]$, then the answer is no.

For a concrete example, let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$. Then for any $\theta$ (necessarily in $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$), we have $\mathbf{Z}[\theta] \neq \mathbf{Z} \left[\alpha, \frac{\alpha^2 + \alpha}{2} \right]$, the latter of which is the ring of integers in $\mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. All of this can be proved via methods from basic algebraic number theory.

Comment: Could you add a hint on how you came up with that counterexample?

Comment: The counterexample is due to Dedekind. If you are trying to study which rings of integers are monogenic (i.e. of the form $\mathbf{Z}[\theta]$), then quadratic fields are obviously monogenic and so the first class of fields for which you might try to find an example that is not monogenic is a cubic field.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of info I was hoping for.

Comment: Do you happen to know whether there also is a counterexample with a 'tower' of degree 2 extensions?

Comment: @Anonymous: The ring of integers in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{10})$ is also not monogenic.